# Minimize all windows in View on disconnect

Tags: vdi, vmware-view

I've had several requests from users to see if we can minimize all windows in their View session when they disconnect?  I'm running VMWare View 6.0 with Wyse P25 using PCoIP connecting to a Windows 7 view session.  All View desktops in this pool are Non-Persistent linked clones and when a user moves from one device to another their session follows them.  SO if the user was in their office working on super secret documents and then they are needed out in a public area as soon as they log in anything they had open is visible.  Is there a way to achieve this within View or the View agent?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out how to run commands on disconnect and/or reconnect, then run the Shell commands to Minimise all windows.

I'm not familar with View at all, but it looks like you can set up scripts to run triggered by reconnection events through View specific ADM templates >> [explained here](https://pubs.vmware.com/view-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.view.administration.doc%2FGUID-8FFD8028-FB3F-426B-94A3-DDCF60056A60.html)

Then, run the shell commands in your chosen scripting language. Both of these worked for me on Win 8.

### VBS

set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.MinimizeAll

### Powershell

C:\tools> $shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
C:\tools> $shell.minimizeall()

Comment: Hmm interesting...I'll give it a shot and see what happens.  Thanks!